# UI Router matching url with hash (fragment)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using UI router I need to match URLs with hash (fragment) included in it (HTML5 mode).

```
.state('myState', {
            url: '/path/:id/page#:section',
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            controller: 'MyController'
        });
```

While the setup above works when using ui-sref below..

```
<a ui-sref="myState({id: 1})"> ... // without hash => section == ''
<a ui-sref="myState({id: 1, section: 'abc'})"> ... // section == 'abc'
```

.. it fails when I redirect browser from other page manually by specifying the fragment in the address bar (or when a link including the hash was clicked on totally different site) in that case the URL matcher tries to match against URL without the hash and I am forced to create a new artificial state which is the same as above but without the hash and the param `section` in it's url property. But that leaves me without possibility to have bookmarkable URL with hash included.

I need to have one state, where this fragment param is optional and is correctly matched by in-app state transition and by url matching mechanism when redirected to the page preserving the given `section` parameter (if present).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using `#` param instead:

```
<a ui-sref="myState({id: 1})"> ... // without hash => # == ''
<a ui-sref="myState({id: 1, '#': 'abc'})"> ... // # == 'abc'
```

And URL in the state definition is without hash all together:

```
url: '/path/:id/page',
```

This matches the state on page load with hash in URL, however it still doesn't set the `#` value in state params. I resolved this by manually setting the param in `$stateChangeStart` event handler:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            var hash = $location.hash();
            if (hash) {
                 toParams['#'] = hash;
            }
      }
```